# Pass arguments in shell-script from a makefile and get back the results?

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile, from where I'd like to call a shell-script, which does something and return back the result to makefile.

Detailed description :-

From my make-file, I call the shell-script as follows :-

```
source = $(PWD)
target = $(ROOT)
SCRIPT:= /home/........./temp.sh
FUNCTION:=$(shell $(SCRIPT $source $target))`
```

Shell Script "temp.sh" :-

```
source=$1
target=$2

echo There are $# arguments to $0: $*
common_part=$source # for now
result="" # for now

while [[ "${target#$common_part}" == "${target}" ]]; do
    common_part="$(dirname $common_part)"

    if [[ -z $result ]]; then
        result=".."
    else
        result="../$result"
    fi
done

if [[ $common_part == "/" ]]; then
    result="$result/"
fi

forward_part="${target#$common_part}"

if [[ -n $result ]] && [[ -n $forward_part ]]; then
    result="$result$forward_part"
elif [[ -n $forward_part ]]; then
    result="${forward_part:1}"
fi

echo "Result=$result"
```

- I don't see Shell-Script's "echo statements", what could be the reason of same?
- How can I get the result back to makefile?
- Is this the right way to call a script from make-file?

I'm a newbie in this area.

Answer (score 2):

Your invocation syntax is wrong; you want

```
FUNCTION:=$(shell $(SCRIPT) $(source) $(target))
```

Interpolated Makefile variables need to have a parenthesis around their name unless they are single-letter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When i run above command , i get the following error :     temp.sh: Command not found
temp.sh is present in my current directory. I alos tried with value of scipt to ./temp.sh but still getting the same error. Am i still missing something ? Please correct wherever i am wrong.

Comment: Can't tell from this context. Maybe post a separate question with more specific details.

Comment: In makefile each script runs under subshell. As you can see 'shell' is used before running script. So I suggest do 'cd' to your working dir and then run script.
E.g.
$(shell cd $(WORKING_DIR); ./$(SCRIPT_name) $(source) $(target))

Comment: If you want to know which dir you are in before executing script then do pwd; before 'cd' command